# Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry

Tags: tomcat, ssl, keystore

I am not able to find the keystore generated while doing CSR, hence I have imported the root certs and domain certs by creating a new keystore. The alias given for domain cert is "tomcat". I have edited the server.xml file to point to the new keystore and the keyAlias is given as "tomcat"

However when trying to connect curl throws an "SSL connect error". When I looked at the catalina logs I got the below line-

***java.io.IOException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry***

I have tried with different keystore formats, even using java cacerts as keystore. But nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Share the code in which you are facing this problem.

Comment: This was a Apache tomcat set-up I was doing and does not involve any code

Comment: So your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue by doing the SSL set-up from scratch.

1. Generate a keystore using java keytool. This would generate a public key and private key pair.
2. Using this I created a CSR and gave to CA (certificate authority) who provided new set of certs
3. I exported the private key got in step 1 and combined the private key, certificate received from CA to generate a new keystore (.pfx file) and pointed my Tomcat to the new keystore.

***Notes:***

1. I had issues importing the certs into the keystore created using java keytool. No matter what method I use Tomcat would ultimately not be able to find that cert in the keystore
2. As a workaround, I exported private key from the keystore (using keystore explorer app) then used open ssl to combine the private key and public key
3. While using open ssl, in case the CA provided a chain cert, bundle the root certs and intermediate certs into a single file then use it